# TypeError: setup() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'ctx' and 'message'

Tags: python, discord.py, typeerror

I'm having this problem where my error output says that I am missing 2 positional arguments but they are defined.
if you didnt understand, this is a Cog :)
btw, if you see any problems with my sqlite, please notify me because i am kind of new to sqlite

this is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import sqlite3
import random

class EconCog(commands.Cog, name="Economy"):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):

        db = sqlite3.connect("economy.sqlite")
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS economy(
            Tokens INTEGER,
            Weapons TEXT,
            user_id INTEGER,
            )
        """)

    @commands.command()
    async def addtokens(self, ctx, message, number: int = None):
        if ctx.author.guild_permissions.ban_members:
            author = message.author
            db = sqlite3.connect("economy.sqlite")
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT Tokens FROM economy WHERE user_id = {author.id}")
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            if number is None:
                sql = ("INSERT INTO economy(user_id, Tokens) VALUES (?, ?)")
                val = (author.id, 0, 0)
                cursor.execute(sql, val)
                ctx.send("Please enter a number")
            else:
                sql = ("INSERT INTO economy(user_id, Tokens) VALUES (?, ?)")
                val = (author.id, number, 0)
                cursor.execute(sql, val)
                ctx.send("Done!")
            db.commit()
            cursor.close()
            db.close()

        else:
            await ctx.send("Nice try, but you do not have permission to do that.")

    @commands.command()
    async def removetokens(self, ctx):
        if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.ban_members:
            print("Ok")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Nice try, but you do not have permission to do that.")

async def setup(bot, ctx, message):
    await bot.add_cog(EconCog(bot))
    print("Economy cog has been loaded successfully!")
```

this is the error output that i got:

```
Failed to load extension cogs.economy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 946, in _load_from_module_spec
    await setup(self)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: setup() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'ctx' and 'message'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stene\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\bot\main.py", line 23, in on_ready
    await bot.load_extension(extension)
  File "C:\Users\stene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1012, in load_extension
    await self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "C:\Users\stene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 951, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.economy' raised an error: TypeError: setup() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'ctx' and 'message'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> async def setup(bot, ctx, message):

The `setup` method for cogs only takes `bot` as the argument, nothing else. You can't just add random arguments to functions and expect the library to be able to pass those arguments in.

Also - `setup` is called when you load a cog. At that point there is no `ctx`, and there is no `message`. It's not triggered by anything. Where would the context & the message even come from??

To correctly load cogs, only add `bot` as the argument.

```py
async def setup(bot):
```

If you need anything else to load your cog, you'll have to fetch it some other way. You aren't even *using* `ctx` or `message` though, so not sure what those are even doing there...

Comment: removed it but the same error

Comment: It's literally not possible that you're getting the same error. If the error said that the `bot & message` are arguments are missing, and you've **removed those arguments** from the function, then it can't say that anymore. Because they can't be missing anymore... You probably haven't saved, haven't restarted your bot, or did something the wrong way.

Answer (score -1):

tbh I am not sure what you are trying to do there, but you dont need to pass bot in the command method if that is the code you use. The error is caused because the bot expects the parameters "ctx" and "message" in the discord command. This should work:

```
async def setup(self, ctx):
```

Comment: No, it also won't. This isn't how setup functions work. You **do** need `bot`, it's literally the only thing you need (and the only thing you can use). Also, it's not inside of a class, so adding `self` makes no sense here. This isn't a command, this is a method to load an extension...

Comment: why would you need to pass bot in the command?

Comment: As I said in my comment that you didn't read, **this isn't a command**, it's the setup function to load extensions.